# How to check if a user is logged in gmail in a Web App with "Execute the app as me"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, google-sheets-api, google-apps

I can use getTemporaryActiveUserKey() to retrieve an anonymous temporary gmail identifier but if a user is not logged in at all they are all assigned the same temporary key. How do I check if the user is logged in gmail at all, I need to know this because there is no way to keep track intelligently of that Key as being "not logged in" since it randomly changes every 30 days.

It is so convoluted because I could just submit the app in incognito to find out what the temporary key is for the day for not logged in users but there is a lot of gaps doing it that way.

Comment: Ask them to sign in? You could  implement Google sign in in your app.

Comment: @TheMaster with all these functions you would think there would have been a way, it's almost counter intuitive to even have the userkey. i could login and grab the non login key but i would have to do it every day in case they reset the token.

Comment: @TheMaster The purpose of the app was not to have them login but to segregate anyone who wasn't logged in since they do not get a unique key. In most cases I would agree.

Comment: Use local cookies?

Comment: Are your settings set to "Execute as me" and "Anyone"? If that's the case, users won't be able to access your app without signing into their Google account first. If they use your app, they are logged in. Maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: @AntonDementiev, the problem is, there seems no way to get the email of the user accessing the web app. But if the web app is set to "User accessing the web app", there is a way to get his email.